# What are the model configuration parameters in tensorflow object detection API?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, tensor

In the [Config file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet101_pets.config)  there are some **parameter**s which I don't understand properly . I will mention them here.

**first_stage_features_stride** - Is this the ration of **input/output** ?

**height_stride** (In the first_stage_anchor_generator) - What is this ?

Answer (score 1):

First stage feature stride is describing what is the output stride .

So you have to understand what is the difference between input and output strides . Please go with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44586894/cnn-input-stride-vs-output-stride/45342842#45342842) .

Then height stride is the same , Which describe how an anchor should behave in the real image w.r.t the final feature-map .